# onUnload method on plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, onunload

I'm creating a plugin for WordPress. But
I can't enter the method `onUnload`.

I tried to include it in the body tag, but doesn't work.

Is there a way to use this method?

Comment: can you provide what have you tried?

Comment: attached in tag with js script:
$(BODY).attr('onUnload','nameFunction();');

Comment: Please move the answer to an actual answer, don't let it on the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = nameFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>

window.onbeforeunload = askUser;

function askUser(){
  return “The changes you made will be lost if you navigate away from this page”;
}

</script>
```